# Add a DIV above every image at the same size as image below it

Tags: jquery, dynamic

I am stuck on a bit of jQuery magic I need in my site... I am looking to add a DIV in the code above every image I have with the DIV sized the same as the image - not the image is responsive, so when the image changes size the DIV should also...

I was going with the approach below - but it makes all the DIVs the same size as the last image and not the image that sits above each image...

Code I have so far as below:

```
function placeImageOverDIVFX () {
    $('.projectContentWrapper img').before('<div class="projectContentWrapperOverlayDIV"></div>');
}

placeImageOverDIVFX();
$(window).load(function() { placeImageOverDIVFX(); });

function sizeupImageInnerFX () {
    $('.projectContentWrapper img').each(function () {
        var contentWrapperImageWidth = $(this).width();
        var contentWrapperImageHeight = $(this).height();

        function setSizes () {
            $('.projectContentWrapperOverlayDIV').each(function () {
                $(this).width(contentWrapperImageWidth);
                $(this).height(contentWrapperImageHeight);
            });
        }

        setSizes();
    });
}

sizeupImageInnerFX();

$(window).load(function() { sizeupImageInnerFX(); });
$(window).resize(function() { sizeupImageInnerFX(); });
```

Any ideas on how to make the DIV sizes specific to the image directly below each "projectContentWrapperOverlayDIV" DIV?

HTML markup example below:

```
<div class="projectContentWrapper">

<img src="assets/images/work/01/01.jpg">
<img src="assets/images/work/01/02.jpg">
<img src="assets/images/work/01/03.jpg">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just have a logic issue. 
This `.each()` block grabs the width/height of every image, which is great! I think this codes fine.

```
$('.projectContentWrapper img').each(function () {
    var contentWrapperImageWidth = $(this).width();
    var contentWrapperImageHeight = $(this).height();
    setSizes();
});
```

However, when you go to change the size of the div, you're actually iterating over every div, not just the div above your image.

```
function setSizes () {
    $('.projectContentWrapperOverlayDIV').each(function () {
        $(this).width(contentWrapperImageWidth);
        $(this).height(contentWrapperImageHeight);
    });
}
```

The first time through the image loop, all divs with a `.projectContentWrapperDIV` class will update to the first images width/height.  The second time through, it will overwrite the first loops changes and update all the divs to the second images width/height.  This repeats all the way until the last image, which is why all your divs seem to be inheriting the last images width/height.

You need to specifically access the individual div above an image.  You don't have any HTML markup, so I can't give you specifics, but jQuery's [parent()](https://api.jquery.com/parent/) and [closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) will probably help you find it.  If you post the HTML markup we can probably give you a better idea of how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You are making it unnecessarily complected. If I understand you well (Adding div's on images), it can easily be done with CSS. See my example and adjust as needed.

```css
.imager {
  width: 150px; /* Adjust as Needed */
  height: 150px; /* Adjust as Needed */
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative; /* Helps curatil overlap */
  overflow: hidden;  
}


.imager:before {
  content: "IMG";
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background: black;
  z-index: 9;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: .4;
}


/* For the text "IMG" */

.imager:after {
  content: "IMG";
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 150px;
  text-align: center;
  top: 0;
  position: absolute;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 36px;
  color: red;
  
  }

/* IMG Block ends here */




/* Image control starts below */

.imager img {
  width: 100%;
  heihgt: auto;
  margin: 20px 10px 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="imager"><img src="http://i41.tinypic.com/14iiyoy.jpg" border="0" alt="Image and video hosting by TinyPic"> </div>

<div class="imager"><img src="http://i41.tinypic.com/14iiyoy.jpg" border="0" alt="Image and video hosting by TinyPic"> </div>

<div class="imager"><img src="http://i41.tinypic.com/14iiyoy.jpg" border="0" alt="Image and video hosting by TinyPic"> </div>

<div class="imager"><img src="http://i41.tinypic.com/14iiyoy.jpg" border="0" alt="Image and video hosting by TinyPic"> </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an idea, if I understand the question properly. In order to resize the DIVs later on when the fluid images resize I give each div an ID based on it's image's index.

```
$( window ).load((function() {
    $('.projectContentWrapper img').each(function (index) {
        var imageWidth = $(this).width();
        var imageHeight = $(this).height();
        var newDiv = $("<div class='projectContentWrapperOverlayDIV'></div>");
        $(newDiv).width(imageWidth);
        $(newDiv).height(imageHeight);
        $(newDiv).attr("id", "overlay_"+index);
        $(this).before(newDiv);
    }
}

$( window ).resize(function() {
    $('.projectContentWrapper img').each(function (index) {
        var imageWidth = $(this).width();
        var imageHeight = $(this).height();
        $("#overlay_"+index).width(imageWidth).height(imageHeight);
    }
}
```

If the images have IDs, that would be even better. Just use:

```
$(newDiv).attr("id", "overlay_" + this.id );
```

// Not tested of course.